# mysql .net - how to change SQL mode in mysql using .net connector

Tags: mysql, .net, connector

In MySQL Workbench, we have some SQL session modes like 'allow_invalid_dates','traditional', etc.

For example.
`set session sql_mode = 'allow_invalid_dates'`

I am using .net connector for MySQL. so, how do i set these modes using that provider? is there any method for setting the SQL mode?

Comment: Isn't it possible to just send this as a query?

Comment: yes it does work! tried it just now. thanks for the idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, sending the query just like any other query will set the sqlmode for the curret session.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("set session sql_mode = 'allow_invalid_dates'", connection))
    {
        cmd.executeNonQuery();
    }

    //add here any query you want using the new sqlmode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Johan's answer is quite useful. I think you don't need to run it every time after opening a connection if you want to do same in all over the application.

setting this in connection-string will make it work like same as Johan's answer. for reference see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-datetime-invalid.html